# Justifying connection between convergence of Fourier transform and Fourier Series for $L^2$ function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

To prove convergence of Fourier series of $L^2$ function , it sufficient to study the convergence of its Fourier transform. So far I was only able to justify this for function of compact support. How to go about $L^2$ $f$ without compact support ?

Proof for the $f(t) $ of compact support and $\in L^2$  :
clearly $f(t) \in L^1$ without loss of generality assume $f(t)=0$ outside $[-\pi,\pi]$ since we can always replace   $f(t)$ with $f(t')$ such as $t=\frac{n}{2\pi} t'$ for $n \in N$ and $t' \in R$.

define $${g}(s)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-n}^{n}f(t)e^{-ist}dt$$

The relationship between fourier transform and fourier series for $f(t)$ above follows from

$$(1)  \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t+u)\frac{sin(n+\frac{1}{2})u}{2sin(u/2)}du-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t+u)\frac{sin(n+\frac{1}{2})u}{u}du)^2dt=0$$

which is simply consequence of Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma applied to the function $ f (t+u) k (u) $, where $k(u)=\frac{1}{2sin(u/2)}-\frac{1}{u}$  , using remainder term for the Taylor's series of $sin(u/2)$, it easily seen $k(u) $  is bounded over $[-\pi, \pi]$

$$(2)\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-(n+\frac{1}{2})}^{(n+\frac{1}{2})}g(s)e^{ist}ds=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t+u)\frac{sin(n+\frac{1}{2})u}{u}du$$

This can be derived from fubini's theorem and  this theorem : $\mu$ is Lebesgue outer measure, $ A $  is a measurable set with finite measure. For all $n$ ,  $\int_Af_n^2d\mu \le k $ where $ k \in R $ , {$ f_n $} is uniformly integrable

Norm convergence for Fourier series  :
$$(3)  \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t+u)\frac{sin(n+\frac{1}{2})u}{2sin(u/2)}du-f(t))^2dt=0$$

using Riemann Lebesgue Lemma on (2) we have $$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-(n+\frac{1}{2})}^{(n+\frac{1}{2})}g(s)e^{ist}ds=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t+u)\frac{sin(n+\frac{1}{2})u}{u}du$$

Using Norm convergence of fourier series (3), Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, Cauchy-Schwartz Inequality,$a^2+b^2 \ge 2ab$ and (1) and (2) we have:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-(n+\frac{1}{2})}^{n+\frac{1}{2}}g(s)e^{ist}ds-f(t)\right)^2dt=0$$

so if we can show $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-(n+\frac{1}{2})}^{(n+\frac{1}{2})}g(s)e^{ist}ds$$ converges ae .Then according to (1),(2),(3) the Fourier series also converges ae. Actually $ g (s) \in L^2$ based on Plancherel theorem. Interestingly Carleson's theorem proves that the limit above exists ae whenever $ g (s) \in L^2$

Comment: I wouldn't do this. Just prove the desired convergence result directly. It is easy: use orthogonality.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro which result ?

Comment: I wouldn't prove the convergence of Fourier series using the Fourier transform. Prove the convergence of Fourier series directly.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro for functions of bounded variation it is easy but so far ae convergence of fourier series for $ L^2$ function has only be proved using convergence of fourier transform.

Comment: Ah so you are speaking of ae convergence. That's another story. Anyway, if you are speaking of Fourier series, then all functions are compactly supported, because all functions can be considered as defined on the torus $\mathbb T$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro what i was asking is same as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2617588/elementary-proof-of-norm-convergence-of-inverse-fourier-transform-for-l2-func

Comment: What i simlpy did is prove the result when $f $ has compact support

Comment: I think it is enough. All Fourier series can be reduced to functions with compact support.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro u r right. Pls could you help with  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2617588/elementary-proof-of-norm-convergence-of-inverse-fourier-transform-for-l2-func

Answer (score 1):

Proof for $f(t) \in L^2$:

define $f_m=f_{[-m,m]}$ where $m \in N$ and its fourier transform is $\hat{f_m}$

$$\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} f_m=f$$

By Plancherel theorem : $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \hat{f_m}=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-m}^{m}f(t)e^{-ist}dt=\hat{f}$ in sense of $L^2$

our previous result for function with compact support : $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-n}^{n}\hat{f_m}(s)e^{ist}ds-f_m(t))^2dt =0 $$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-n}^{n}\hat{f_m}(s)e^{ist}ds-f_m(t))^2dt=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-n}^{n}\hat{f_m}(s)e^{ist}ds-f_m(t)_{[-\pi,\pi]})^2dt =\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-n}^{n}\hat{f_m}(s)e^{ist}ds-f(t))^2dt=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-n}^{n}\hat{f_n}(s)e^{ist}ds-f(t))^2dt=0 $$

There is a subsequence {$n$} such that $\hat{f_n} \to \hat{f} $ ae. Let's work with such subsequence

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-n}^{n}\hat{f}(s)e^{ist}ds-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-n}^{n}\hat{f_n}(s)e^{ist}ds)^2dt =$$$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f(t+u)_{[-\infty,-n]}+f(t+u)_{[n,\infty]})\frac{sin(n+\frac{1}{2})u}{u}du)^2dt $$ $$\le 2(||f(u)_{[-\infty,-n]}+f(u)_{[n,\infty]}||_{L^2}+||\frac{sin(n+\frac{1}{2})u}{u}||_{L^2})^{-1/2}$$ by Cauchy-Scwartz ineqaulity

because $a^2+b^2 \ge 2ab$ , it follows from Cauchy-Schwartz inequality that:

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-n}^{n}\hat{f}(s)e^{ist}ds-f(t))^2dt\le$ 
$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(|\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-n}^{n}\hat{f}(s)e^{ist}ds-f_n(t)|+|f_n(t)-f(t)|)^2dt=0 $

we proved the result for some sequence {$n$} to see the result holds for all $n$ we observe that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-(n+1)}^{(n+1)}\hat{f}(s)e^{ist}ds-\int_{-n}^{n}\hat{f}(s)e^{ist}ds)^2dt \le$$$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-(n+1)}^{(-n)}|\hat{f(s)}|ds+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{n}^{(n+1)}|\hat{f(s)}|ds)^2dt \le \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2\pi} (||\hat{f}_{[-n-1,-n]}||_{L^2}+||\hat{f}_{[n,n+1]}||_{L^2})^2=0$$ by Hölder's Inequality